# Flex bug when trying to wrap multiple tables in current version of Safari?

Tags: css, safari

Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work in MacOS Safari 13.0.4?  The second table bleeds out of the containing box.  Chrome and Firefox both manage to contain everything within the div, as expected.

How can it be fixed?

```css
div {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            width: 800px;
            background: #f99
        }

        table {
            flex-basis: 300px;
            flex-shrink: 1;
            flex-grow: 1;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
                    the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
                    the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
                    the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

If I change the tables to divs it works correctly, but this is obviously a minimal example - the tables are required on the final solution.

(Normally I'd make a jsfiddle to link, but their site seems to be broken for me at the moment; can edit but it won't run or give me a sharable url.)

Thank you.

Comment: Add [CSS Prefixes](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to the stylesheet. That will make it browser invariant.

Comment: That won't make any difference.  It would if I was targeting an old outdated browser version, but I'm not.  The current version of Safari (and all other mainstream browsers) require no prefixes, and in fact their use is discouraged.

Comment: I've now recoded this page of my site to use nested flexboxes, rather than the tables it needed before.  It's fixed the problem, by avoiding the problem.